# Windows 7 acts like my speakers have a loose connection but they don't, could this be a bug?

Tags: windows-7, audio

I just upgraded my computer to Windows 7. Now a message keeps popping up that my speakers have been unplugged, and the sound will cut out. After a while, I get a message that they have been plugged in, and the sound will start playing again.

Now, this might be a loose connection, or maybe the plug is broken somehow, but I suspect it might be some kind of bug. The speakers are firmly plugged in, twisting and nudging the plug or even unplugging and replugging it when it's not working makes no difference, plugging in different speakers makes no difference either, and I never had this problem until I updated the software.

Is there a way to tell whether my hardware is broken or whether this is some kind of bug? Any ideas for fixing or troubleshooting?

Edit: In case it matters, I use the Realtek HD Audio Manager, and the sound card driver should be up to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem when I first got Windows 7, uninstalling Realtek HD Audio Manager fixes it because if there is not enough CPU Realtek stops working, If you have a **need** for the manager then you need more CPU so there is enough to run Realtek all the time.

Comment: It looks like that might have fixed it, thank you!